# Memory slice using malloc by slicing one big malloc'd memory

Tags: c, malloc, free

Consider an application that invokes `malloc()` and `free()` many times. The application allocates a total of say 1000 bytes in total.

I am trying to write a code where we reduce number of `malloc` / `free` calls by slicing one big malloc'd memory and then freeing it up:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct A
{
    char *s;
    int data;
};

struct B
{
    float len;
    char net;
    int data[];
};

struct C
{
    float len;
    char net;
    int data[10];
    struct B *b;
}; 

int main() {
    int s =0;
    char *p = malloc(1000);
    char *mem = p;
    //Alocate for struct A from above pool
    struct A *a = (struct A *)p;
    p += sizeof(struct A);
    struct B *b = (struct B *)p ;
    p += sizeof(struct B) + sizeof(int) * 3; //data[0]..data[2]
    struct C *c = (struct C *)p;
    free(mem);
    return 0;
}
```

Is this a legitimate approach for my issue? Is there any flaw in my code or scenarios that I have missed and can cause problem?

Comment: That's exactly what `malloc()` and `free()` already do. Do you have some reason for (a) thinking you have an 'issue' in the first place, and (b) thinking you can do better than `malloc()/free()` already do?

Comment: In actual code we have a memory leak and its difficult to find the exact location. The total memory allocated in production code is 177.66 KB and is a custom library code. I was thinking to just wrap the library custom malloc / free functions

Comment: To find leaks, run a build compiled using `-fsanitize=address`, or run the program using `valgrind`.

Comment: @Programmer, How is re-implementing a complex tested system going to *prevent* memory leaks!?

Comment: Writing more code isn't going to solve the problems in the existing code.

Comment: Unfortunately it a application that runs on a embedded board. I am unable to run valgrind on same

Comment: If your existing allocations are buggy, how is wrapping them going to solve that? You're shooting alligators when the objective is to, err, drain the swamp.

Comment: @ikegame - some where free is not called or done properly, For this to fix we would need to understand the whole custom library. In my example no matter what library flow does all memory allocated in heap will be freed. So I replace malloc call to return address carefully

Comment: So somebody isn't calling `free()`. So how is writing another one going to solve that?

Comment: As stated in malloc wrapper function I will suppress malloc call and return address as shown in my example in question

Comment: Another problem with your approach is that you're ignoring alignment.  If you allocate a character array of 5 characters, followed by a double, you will most likely end up with a misaligned pointer for the double.  `malloc` guarantees that any returning pointer will satisfy the most restrictive alignment requirement of any data type.  Your code should probably do the same, unless you place your own restrictions on the supported sizes and alignments.

Comment: You should not use dynamic memory allocation in embedded systems, because they are typically have to be long running and independent, and dynamic memory allocation introduces a lot of unpredictability. Use static preallocations instead.

Comment: [Why should I not use dynamic memory allocation in embedded systems?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/286121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is an *arena allocator*, and it's a perfectly normal technique in some contexts.

Once you've fixed the alignment issue, and organised your code as a deliberate and self-contained arena, you'll find

- it doesn't fix, or easily deal with, fragmentation. So, you may end up using more memory overall depending on your allocation patterns
- it doesn't make it any easier (or harder) to correctly match allocations to deallocations
- it does allow you to release (or reset) the whole arena in one go, so any missing deallocations don't create permanent leaks.

  (They're still temporary leaks, in that they increase pressure & fragmentation on the arena between resets)

Sometimes it makes sense not to worry about deallocation at all, until reset. That sidesteps the first two points, but whether it is acceptable depends entirely on your allocation patterns (and how much memory you can afford to waste).

Knowing the name of the technique, it should be easy to find working examples.

Answer (score 2):

You are in great risk of just adding new error sources...

While being rather low level, the `malloc`-`free` pair is designed to avoid alignment problem. That will be the first question to considere if you want to re-implement it.

Next mistakes are easy in memory addresses computation.

Those lines seem to be ok:

```
char *p = malloc(1000);          // ok char pointer on newly allocated memory
char *mem = p;                   // id.

struct A* a = (struct A*)p;      // ok as you are at the start of the malloc'ed block
p += sizeof(struct A);           // ok, p now points just past a

p += sizeof(struct B) + sizeof(int) * 3;  // ok,if there is no alignment problem (1)

free(mem);                                // ok, you release the full bloc
```

(1) actually reserved some memory for a B struct having an array data of size 3, *provided p was initially correctly aligned* for a B struct

This one seems far more problematic:

```
struct B* b = (struct A*)p + sizeof(int) * 3;//data[0]..data[2] ???
```

`(struct A*)p` will be a pointer to `struct A`. If you add integer values to it, you are considering it as a pointer to the initial element of an array of `struct A`. So `b` will skip `3*sizeof(int)`, meaning 6, 12 or 24 depending of int size, *elements of size of `struct A`*!

This code is a hint that you could let some errors sneak in your new library. Are you sure you will really trust it?

Comment: That's actually a typo error it would be something like -     struct B *b = (struct B *)p ;
    p += sizeof(struct B) + sizeof(int) * 3; //data[0]..data[2]